# nginx configuration to allow allias url to access my current url

Tags: nginx

Mu current Nginx configuration is working fine with this url:
https://myhostname.com

But I have created a different alias for same server, say myhostname1

Now when I try to access the url

https://myhostname1.com

it throws error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://sg-stg-bms-cdn001.eng.vmware.com//scripts/services/appStatusService.js?pingpong=2831234.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://myhostname.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'https://myhostname1.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Both the host myhostname and myhostname1 is pointing to same IP and DNS entry.

I tried adding this line to my nginx configuration but that seems not working

```
   location / {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
..........
```

But still that doesn't seems to be working. Can anyone please help wher I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,2531,2533) is probably more helpful than my summary but: either 'include (/path/to/sites-enabled)' at the end of your document and at that location have a config file detailing enabled sites, or, add blocks on a per-server basis (server{port; path; name; etc} you should already have one in the appropriate file for server{listen 80; server_name myhostname.com; index index.htm; root /path/to/root/folder}).

Answer (score 0):

This message is telling you that your request violates [javascript's same-origin security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). If you're accessing the site with a browser, that message is probably coming from the browser, not from nginx. The same-origin policy in javascript security protects users from malicious websites attempting to use the browser's javascript to interact with other websites. Without this sandboxing, a malicious webpage could use the browser's javascript engine to interact with other websites -- perhaps change the user's email password, edit her facebook page, and so on.

You can selectively extend this security by adding http headers for [cross-origin sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Nginx can do this for you. Here's how:

1. If your config includes this directive, `add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";`, remove it (or comment out). That removes a security provision that tells browsers to disallow CORS.
2. Selectively extend cross-site scripting by adding CORS headers to requests. In the location block of each host, add these directives:

   > ```
   > add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
   > add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
   > add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST' always;
   > add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
   > ```

Using "$http_origin" limits CORS to *.yourdomain.com, but you can also use `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always`, opening CORS to all sites -- a weaker security model. Newer versions of nginx require a third argument (`always` in this example). You're missing that in your config.

Comment: I tried adding add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always

But it doesn't seems to be working.. not sure where I am missing

Comment: Did you do everything I listed in my answer or only that one directive? You need all of it.